# Is it possible to wake up iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I would like to know if it's possible to programatically wake up the iPhone from sleep? I have an NSTimer set to play a sound after a certain amount of time, but I also want it to wake up the iPhone when the timer rings. Is this at all possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't at this time.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications will wake up the phone, but that's probably way overkill.